# Django how to store forms data from several pages into one table

Tags: django, django-forms, django-users

I'm building a django project, and creating user profile app. But I want user to complete creating profile process in multiple pages. For example: first page fill in the address and phone number, and then user click "continue" to the second page, where user can fill in some other things like gender, date of birth. But I want to store all this information into one table.

What I used to do is store the first page's data into some hidden field, and pass to the next page and submit them at the final page. Is that the correct and secure way? How django handle this condition?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Django's [FormWizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)